# How to use a JavaScript variable in a table layout?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

This is my code:

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data1 = "$100";
    var data2 = "$80";
</script>
<body>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

I need to replace this $100 & $80 with JavaScript variable data1 & data2

How to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by replace? switch between `100$` and `80$` ?

Comment: No just make use of variables :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you assign `id`s to the cells you want

```
<td id="data1">$100</td> 

<td id="data2">$80</td>
```

You can set their value in Javascript like this

```
document.getElementById("data1").innerHTML = data1;
document.getElementById("data2").innerHTML = data2;
```

[You can see this in action on jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/2cPPL/)

Answer (score 1):

**If** I understood you right, and you want to replace between `100$` and `80$`:

```
var data1 = "$100";
var data2 = "$80";

var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('td');

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    console.log(elements[i]);
    if (elements[i].innerHTML == data1) 
        elements[i].innerHTML = data2;
    else if (elements[i].innerHTML == data2) 
        elements[i].innerHTML = data1;
}​
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/DQt9p/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data1 = "$100";
    var data2 = "$80";
</script>
<body>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td onload="this.textContent=data1;"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td onload="this.textContent=data2;"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

HTML5 has no explicit databinding options, but has data- tags to insert metadata to DOM elements. [More info](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/)

If you still need a more responsive way to bind your data you can try [this post](http://blogs.claritycon.com/blog/2011/02/20/mvvm-databinding-javascript-with-knockout-html5-boilerplate/)